# Storing Primary Key of table to Foreign key of another table -- Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to store the primary key of `department` table to `section` table.

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('tbl_department', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('id')->primary();
      $table->string('department_name')->nullable();
      $table->softDeletes();
      $table->timestamps();
    });

 Schema::create('tbl_section', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->string('department_id');
            $table->foreign('department_id')
                        ->references('id')
                        ->on('tbl_department')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('section_name')->nullable();
      $table->softDeletes();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Department Model**

```
class DepartmentModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_department';
    protected $fillable = ['department_name'];

public function section () {
    return $this->hasMany('App\SectionModel', 'department_id'); 
}
```

**Section Model**

```
class SectionModel extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'tbl_section';
    protected $fillable = ['department_id', 'section_name'];



    public function department () {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\DepartmentModel', 'department_id');    
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $request->validate ([
            'department' => 'required',
            'section' => 'required'
        ]);

        DepartmentModel::create ([
            'department_name' => $request->department,
    ]);

    SectionModel::create ([
            'section_name' => $request->section,
    ]);

        return redirect()->route('department.index');
  }
```

Comment: Hey @jim, change datatype string to $table->bigIncrements('id'); or $table->increments('id'); in your tables

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that custom primary key as string would not work in a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit this ...

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('tbl_department', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    ...
});

Schema::create('tbl_section', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    ...
});
```

**Section Model**

```
public function department() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DepartmentModel', 'id');  
}
```

**Controller**

```
$departament = DepartmentModel::create ([
    'department_name' => $request->department,
]);

SectionModel::create ([
    'section_name' => $request->section,
    'department_id' => $departament->id
]);
```

Comment: This works thank you very much! Though both of @jinal and your code works, I much prefer this one since it's more readable especially for members of the team who don't have much experience with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

try below:

1. change datatype string of 'id' column to `$table->increments('id');` in your tables.
2. Edit relationship method in Section Model:

   ```
   public function department() 
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\DepartmentModel', 'id');    
   }
   ```
3. In controller file:

   ```
   $departament = DepartmentModel::create([
       'department_name' => $request->department
   ]);

   $department->sections()->create([
       'section_name' => $request->section
   ]);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

here the solution,

```
User Table

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('firstname', 30);
    $table->string('lastname', 30);
    $table->string('email', 60)->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password', 191);
    $table->string('phone', 15)->nullable();
    $table->text('address')->nullable();
    $table->string('town', 60)->nullable();
    $table->integer('zip_code')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
});

Cart Table

Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
});
```